# Need a snippet to output long date with date ordinals in TextExpander

Tags: windows, date, textexpander

I use TextExpander on Windows and have googled for an solution to my problem. All the solutions I've seen so far are written in AppleScript which doesn't work on Windows.

The format I need looks like this:

- Monday, 1**st** August 2016
- Tuesday, 2**nd** August 2016
- Wednesday, 3**rd** August 2016
- Thursday, 4**th** August 2016

and so on. Notice the parts in bold.

I've tried using the date/time tools included with TextExpander but the st, nd, rd and th ordinals are not included.

I don't know any scripting at all. Is there a script for this long date format that will work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the conditional "st", "nd", "rd", or "th" after the date, then:

**%A**, %d %B %Y

In this example I made the Day of the week bold to demonstrate how the result will show up bold as well. Of course it is only an option.

If you do want the extra suffix with nothing bold, then:

%A, %d%fillpopup:name=Suffix:default=:st:nd:rd:th% %B %Y

I Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But `%A, %d%fillpopup:name=Suffix:default=:st:nd:rd:th% %B %Y` doesn't work. What happens is, I get a pop-up box that has a drop menu with the ordinals listed. So for example I selected the "th" ordinal from the drop menu, then clicked Ok. Then I got this error: `JavaScript Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'` in place of the date in my document. Note, in TextExpander, the content is set to JavaScript, and I am not familiar with JS.